# Using bisect to flip coins

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-limit-exceeded, binary-search

I am trying to solve [this problem on Codechef](https://www.codechef.com/problems/FLIPCOIN), which has a list of \$N\$ coins, all initially tails-up, and a list of \$Q\$ commands. There are two possible commands, `0 A B` flips all coins in the interval `[A, B]` and `1 A B` prints the number of heads-up coins in the interval `[A, B]` (both intervals include `B`).

After reviewing [somebody else's answer that exceeded the time-limit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/185980/98493), I came up with a [fast `numpy` answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/185983/98493), which was still not fast enough for the online judge (3s instead of 0.3s).

However, one other reviewer [suggested the following algorithm](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/186000/98493):

> - The key observation is that a `0 a b` operation is in fact a pair of operations: flip coins from `a` to the end, and flip coins from `b + 1` to the end. This leads to the solution:
>
>   - Decouple the `0 a b` operation into `a` and `b+1`
>   - Maintain the list of flip points, and keep it ordered
>   - To perform a `1` operation, find the largest flip point before `A`. If its index in flip list is even, the `A` coin is tails
>       up, otherwise it is heads up. Then, traverse the flip list until `B`
>       adding up lengths of every other interval.

I tried to implement this, using [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) to keep the list of flips sorted, but it is a lot slower (20s for the same worst-case input as the 3s quoted above).

```
from bisect import bisect_left, insort

n, q = map(int, input().split())

flips = []

for _ in range(q):
    command, start, end = map(int, input().split())
    if command == 0:
        insort(flips, start)
        insort(flips, end + 1)
    elif command == 1:
        flip_start = bisect_left(flips, start)
        flip_end = bisect_left(flips, end + 1)
        flips_temp = flips[flip_start:flip_end]
        insort(flips_temp, end + 1)
        if flip_start % 2:
            insort(flips_temp, start)
        print(sum(flips_temp[1::2]) - sum(flips_temp[:-1:2]))
```

However, this is probably not the best implementation of that algorithm, maybe there is a way to use [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) to keep the list sorted (but then slicing and traversing it become harder). So, any comments, especially on how to speed this up, are welcome.

I am aware that one should normally put this into a function and make it re-usable, but since this is time-critical code I think it is fine to leave it all in the global namespace. It is a one-shot script, anyway.

---

The worst-case input file I used (which I generated using the code in my linked answer from above) can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/graipher/221a969cc84574982a3eed91be3c60d0) (1.4 MB). It assumes the maximum allowed values for \$N\$ and \$Q\$ and contains a random sequence of the two allowed commands.

I feed it to this code with the following command (and time it at the same time):

```
time cat flipping_coins.dat | python3 flipping_coins.py
```

Running only the `cat` command already takes 0.17s.

---

[As Ev. Kounis noted in the comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186041/using-bisect-to-flip-coins#comment354706_186041), there is currently no solution in pure Python that successfully beats this challenge. There are, however, a couple of PyPy solutions, which use segment trees.

Comment: I would also like to comment that currently there is **no** successful pure Python solution to raise the *"bounty"* and *stakes* a bit.

Comment: There is now a successful pure Python solution, though only for Python 2, as mentioned [in this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/186043/121325)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>     if command == 0:
>         insort(flips, start)
>         insort(flips, end + 1)
> ```

Well, the main reason it's slow is `insort`. As the doc says,

> Keep in mind that the O(log n) search is dominated by the slow O(n) insertion step.

That said, there's a significant performance improvement possible here without changing data structure. Flipping coins from `a` to the end and then flipping coins from `a` to the end is equivalent to doing absolutely nothing. So rather than always insert, toggle whether or not the value is in `flips`. I see an execution time reduction from about 30s to about 16s with

```
def toggle(flips, val):
    idx = bisect_left(flips, val)
    if idx < len(flips) and flips[idx] == val:
        del flips[idx]
    else:
        flips.insert(idx, val)
```

and

```
    if command == 0:
        toggle(flips, start)
        toggle(flips, end + 1)
```

Obviously if you want speed then you need to switch to using a better data structure than a list, but within the constraints of list I think this is fairly efficient.

---

> ```
>     elif command == 1:
>         flip_start = bisect_left(flips, start)
>         flip_end = bisect_left(flips, end + 1)
>         flips_temp = flips[flip_start:flip_end]
>         insort(flips_temp, end + 1)
>         if flip_start % 2:
>             insort(flips_temp, start)
>         print(sum(flips_temp[1::2]) - sum(flips_temp[:-1:2]))
> ```

The first thing that's suspicious here is `insort`. However, to my surprise, using `flips_temp.append(end + 1)` and `flips_temp.insert(0, start)` made things slightly slower. The real speedup comes from eliminating the copying. Careful analysis shows that the logic is equivalent to

```
    elif command == 1:
        flip_start = bisect_left(flips, start)
        flip_end = bisect_left(flips, end + 1)

        accum = sum(flips[flip_start+1:flip_end:2]) - sum(flips[flip_start:flip_end:2])
        if flip_start % 2:
            accum = -start - accum
        if flip_end % 2:
            accum = accum + end + 1
        print(accum)
```

This gave me a further speedup from 16 seconds to 12 seconds.

IMO it would make sense to implement the difference of sums using `functools.reduce(operator.sub, ..., 0)`, but that's much much slower (~40 seconds).